# More elaborate manual installation instructions

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I'm on another platform than Ubuntu, but would like to test Ubuntu Touch on a Nexus 7. The manual installation instructions at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install use adb - but does not work for me. Would it be possible to add fastboot instructions, or access to the phablet-flash scripts?

Answer (score -2):

copy both zips onto the sdcard and use a clockwork recovery mod or twrp to flash both zips. be sure to do a factory reset. works for raring but i havent successfully done this with the latest saucy releases